# How to download and install imageJLibrary in netbeans

Tags: image-processing, imagej, java

I'm new to java and image processing. I want to develop a java application with functionalities like thresholding and hitorgrams related operations. I have considered about 2 image processing libraries; JAI and imageJ.

I have found that imajeJ is more suitable, but when i searched for it to download i only found a tool instead of a library. Can someone tell me where i can download imageJ api(/library) and install it, so i can use it in netbeans.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download the latest ImageJ jar from [here](http://rsb.info.nih.gov/ij/ij.jar) and add it as an external library for your project. You can then program to the API as described in the [API documentation](http://rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/developer/api/index.html). The servlet example provided [here](http://www.imagingbook.com/index.php?id=102) may be of use.